# How to set div 100% height inside ng-view directive?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I noticed that in order to set 100% height of a div with `Bootstrap` (or without), you should first set the `html` and `body` tags to 100% height.

Then, each child of those parents will inherit the height.

It works, however when doing the same thing under `ng-view` directive, the child does not inherit the height of the `html` and `body`.

This is my code:

```
<html ng-app="AngularApp" style="height:100%">
...
<body style="height:100%; overflow-y: scroll; overflow-x: hidden">

    <div ng-view style="height:100%"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And inside the `ng-view` I am have this:

```
<div class="" style="height:100%; background-color:black">

</div>
```

As mentioned above, when doing the same thing outside the `ng-view` directive it works, only when this directive comes in action it does not work.

For simplicity, I have added the CSS in the inputs and not in a remote file.

Comment: Maybe it will help if you create an extra css class, in where you declare `height:inherit !important;` and add this to your target div.

Comment: Have you checked the actual resulting DOM structure? Maybe this directive causes the insertion of additional HTML container elements in between somewhere, so that your “chain” of setting 100% height gets broken ... // 
If you just want an element to take the full viewport height, then use `100vh` instead of percent ... that doesn’t even need a height to specified for the parent.